# I need advice organising and digitising old photos

Tags: scanning, archive, digital-preservation

Hello I have approx 1000 photos all mixed up from early 1900’s up to about 10 years ago. I’d like to digitise them so I can stop worrying about loss or damage. Are their any services out there that will sort them all and scan them for me? Can an expert tell from the film/paper/watermarks/negatives enough to put them in a timeline or batches? Thanks :)

Comment: https://www.toptenreviews.com/best-photo-scanning-services Be aware that if you send your photos to someone else, there is always a risk that they will be lost.

Comment: I don't think you'll find someone who can just look at a print (front or back) and date it just like that. Everyone will probably have to do a bit of research/googling, and you may have reasonable luck simply giving it a shot yourself. What identifiers are on your prints/negatives?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you need as an answer here.

To answer exactly what you asked,

1. Yes to scanning, sorting would be a premium. Probably better to do that yourself.
   You would probably be far better at this than a 3rd party, as you will know Aunt Edna is younger than Granny Weatherwax but older than Cousin Itt, & be able to timeline based on those cues.
2. Yes, probably, with a margin of error. Again, they would want to be paid for this, depending on the extent of the research necessary. You'd probably be as well just knowing "these are from the 50s… ish, before Great Uncle Eric got his wig" than more precise dates.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response one of the problems with the really old ones is no-one alive knows what order they go in! Ha ha! I’m not really bothered how much it costs I just want some to say “they look like they’re from the same batch, or at least “these are 1920’s, 1930’s” etc. I wondered if to the expert eye you could tell which photos “belong” together if you know what I mean. From 80’s onwards I can probably manage it myself, but the early ones are difficult.

Comment: To finesse the details you're gonna have to get on the phone. You're probably looking for "the old guy who still does a few of these jobs in his spare time" rather than "Happy Snappy inc with an average employee age of 23". You want someone who can hold your hand through the process, probably including a personal visit to their shop, & not just say "Sure, they'll be ready Wednesday"